# html5 autofocus not working with google maps v3 infowindow form

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple Google Maps v3 application that displays markers with InfoWindow popups each with a small form.  I want the focus to immediately be on the single input element when the InfoWindow pops up, but so far no luck. Below is a sample of the code I'm using...

```
var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

var content = "<div id='infobox'>"+
           "Rodney F. Stanley<hr>803-555-5555<br>"+ 
           "1 mile north of allenville<br>"+
           "<form name='report' action='updateNotes.php' method='POST'>"+ 
           "<input type='hidden' name='warningID' value='13874794739749' />"+
           "<input type='hidden' name='spotterID' value='SC00023' />"+
           "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='Rodney F. Stanley' />"+
           "<input type='text' name='report' size='25' maxsize='150' placeholder='event and time of occurence' autofocus />"+
           "<input type='submit' value='submit' /><br>"+
           "</form>"+
           "</div>";


infowindow1.setContent(content);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function() { 
if(openwindow){
    eval(openwindow).close();
}
openwindow=infowindow1;
infowindow1.open(map,marker1); 
    });
```

**FINAL SOLUTION (just the listener)...**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function() { 
if(openwindow){
    eval(openwindow).close();
}
openwindow=infowindow1;
infowindow1.open(map,marker1); 

    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow1, 'domready', function() {
            $("#report").focus();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the domready event of the infowindow and set focus manually.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {

    // Set focus on your input here. Below in jQuery.
    $("#yourInput").focus();
});
```

This will work. Autofocus won't work here.

Comment: Thanks, MrUpsidown!  That did it!

Comment: I removed your comment. If you want, add it as an edit of your question to allow others to see clearly how you did it.